# Wordpress Technical Terms

Tags: web, wordpress

I'm working on designing a site in WP, but I'm at a loss for the right words to google. What I'm looking for is a "text container that can be toggled". I have a syntax highlighting plugin for posting code, but I don't want the code to be visible in large blocks considering it may be a little distracting. I was wondering if anyone could link me to a plugin or give me the technical term for what I'm thinking of, where you can put the text in a group and then be able to toggle whether it is visible or not within the page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is simply applying a CSS class to the element and then using jQuery or some other JS library to toggle its visibility. Example below (code is not optimized in order to explain some of the concepts. This can, read "should", be cleaned up):

```
// This is HTML/CSS
<body>
...
<p>Here is some normal text.</p>
<a href="#" id="source_code_displayText_method_toggle_link">Show/hide source code for displayText method</a>
<div class="source_code" id="source_code_for_displayText_method">
     // Groovy code
     ...
     public void displayText(String message) {
         outputStream.write(message)
     }
     ...
</div>
...
<a href="#" id="source_code_download_method_toggle_link">Show/hide source code for download method</a>
<div class="source_code" id="source_code_for_download_method">
     // Groovy code
     ...
     GParsPool.withPool(threads) {
            sessionDownloadedFiles = localUrlQueue.collectParallel { URL url ->
                downloadFileFromURL(url)
            }
        }
     ...
</div>
...
<a href="#" id="source_code_all_toggle_link">Show/hide all source code sections</a>
...
</body>
```

You can default all source code sections to hidden:

```
// This is CSS
.source_code {
  display: hidden;
}
```

Then you would use JS to provide the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) ability:

```
// This is JavaScript

// This toggles a specific section by using an id ("#") selector
$('#source_code_displayText_method_toggle_link').onClick(function() {
  $('#source_code_for_displayText_method').toggle();
});

// This toggles all source code sections by using a class (".") selector
$('#source_code_all_toggle_link').onClick(function() {
  $('.source_code').toggle();
});
```

Some thoughts:

- If you toggle all sections, you need to determine what the current state is -- if some are currently shown and others hidden, this will invert each. If you want "hide all" and "show all", then use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) respectively.
- If you are manually adding the source code sections and want semantic selectors, the above is fine. If you are building some kind of automation/tool to allow you to repeat this, you'll probably want to use generated ids and helper links, in which case it would look like:

.

```
// This is HTML/CSS
<body>
...
<p>Here is some normal text.</p>
<a href="#" class="source_code_toggle_link" id="source_code_toggle_link_1">Show/hide source code for displayText method</a>
<div class="source_code" id="source_code_1">
     // Groovy code
     ...
     public void displayText(String message) {
         outputStream.write(message)
     }
     ...
</div>
...
<a href="#" class="source_code_toggle_link" id="source_code_toggle_link_2">Show/hide source code for download method</a>
<div class="source_code" id="source_code_2">
     // Groovy code
     ...
     GParsPool.withPool(threads) {
            sessionDownloadedFiles = localUrlQueue.collectParallel { URL url ->
                downloadFileFromURL(url)
            }
        }
     ...
</div>
...
<a href="#" id="source_code_all_toggle_link">Show/hide all source code sections</a>
...
</body>
```

With the JavaScript to handle id parsing:

```
// This is JavaScript

// This toggles a specific section by using a dynamic id ("#") selector
$('.source_code_toggle_link').onClick(function(elem) {
  var id = $(elem).attr("id");
  // Split on the _ and take the last element in the resulting array
  var idNumber = id.split("_")[-1];
  var codeBlock = $('#source_code_' + idNumber);
  codeBlock.toggle();
});
```